# Optimising my C loop for a combinatorial problem

Tags: c, loops, optimization, heuristics

I need to find a permutation vector such that a 250x250 matrix reaches a maximal cost (sum of the elements in the superior triangle). Consider the cost function as a black box for my question. My neighborhood strategies are:

- exchange 2 elements of the permutation vector
- make an insertion of an element of the permutation vector elsewhere

I also have 2 pivotation rules:

- first improvement
- best improvement

My problem is: **the loop is too long to execute**. I should have a 20x slower code for this exercise, and I don't see were I could optimize my loop.

To do so, I use 3 loops. Here is the pseudo code (`transform()` can be either exchange, or insert, so a function using 2 indices `(k, l)` of the permutation vector `currentSolution`):

```
currentSolution = randomSolution(randomSeed)
bestCost = cost(currentSolution)

reapeat:
    for each element k in currentSolution:
        for each element l in currentSolution:
            currentSolution = transform(currentSolution, k, l)
            newCost = cost(currentSolution)
            if newCost > bestCost:
                depending on pivotation rule, update parameters (e.g. best_k, bestCost, ...)
                depending on pivotation rule, stop the loops or revert transformation
            else:
                revert transformation of currentSolution
        end
    end
    if at least one tuple (k, l) improves currentSolution:
       currentSolution = transform(currentSolution, best_k, best_l) if not already done
    else:
        Found local optimum. Stop the search.
end
```

Now, here is the C code for the best improvement (insertion strategy):

```
while (i < EARLY_STOPPING) {
    i++;
    best_k = -1; best_l = -1; breakOuterLoop = 0;
    for (k = 0; k <= PSize - 1; k++) {
        for (l = 0; l <= PSize - 1; l++) {
            if (l == k) continue;
            insertElement(currentSolution, k, l);
            newCost = computeCost(currentSolution);
            if (newCost > bestCost) {
                bestCost = newCost; best_k = k; best_l = l;
            }
            undoInsertion(currentSolution, k, l); // Put it back in place anyway
        }
        if (breakOuterLoop) break;
    }
    if (best_k >= 0) insertElement(currentSolution, best_k, best_l); // found a better k, l
    else { // local optimum
        break;
    }
    
    if (i >= EARLY_STOPPING) {
        break;
    }
}
```

NB: I know I could improve computeCost, but I am looking for another solution.

Here are the implementations of insertElement and undoInsertion, though I don't think there is a problem here:

```
void insertElement(long int* solution, int k, int l) {
    if (k < l) {
        long int temp = solution[k];
        for (int i = k; i < l; i++) {
            solution[i] = solution[i + 1];
        }
        solution[l] = temp;
    } else if (k > l) {
        long int temp = solution[k];
        for (int i = k; i > l; i--) {
            solution[i] = solution[i - 1];
        }
        solution[l] = temp;
    }
    // No operation needed if k == l, as an element cannot be inserted into its current position
}

void undoInsertion(long int* solution, int k, int l) {
    if (k < l) {
        long int temp = solution[l];
        for (int i = l; i > k; i--) {
            solution[i] = solution[i - 1];
        }
        solution[k] = temp;
    } else if (k > l) {
        long int temp = solution[l];
        for (int i = l; i < k; i++) {
            solution[i] = solution[i + 1];
        }
        solution[k] = temp;
    }
    // No operation needed if k == l, as an element cannot be "un-inserted" from its current position
}
```

How can I make my execution faster?

---

**Edit**: Here is the Makefile for the ones wondering how I compiled this project:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-O3 -Wall

OBJECTS=src/instance.o src/main.o src/optimization.o src/timer.o src/utilities.o

.PHONY: clean

all: lop

lop: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o lop

clean:
    rm -f src/*~ src/*.o lop
```

Here is also the computeCost function:

```
long long int computeCost (long int *s ) {
    int h,k;
    long long int sum;
    
    /* Diagonal value are not considered */
    for (sum = 0, h = 0; h < PSize; h++ ) 
    for ( k = h + 1; k < PSize; k++ )
        sum += CostMat[s[h]][s[k]];

    return(sum);
}
```

---

**Second edit**: I have been asked the full code. Here is main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "instance.h"
#include "utilities.h"
#include "timer.h"
#include "optimization.h"

#define EARLY_STOPPING 20000

// Constants for first improvement pruning
#define IS_FIRST_THRESHOLD_MUTABLE 1
#define MIN_FIRST_THRESHOLD 50
#define FIRST_THRESHOLD_FACTOR_REDUCTION 2
long int FIRST_THRESHOLD = 10000;  // this value must stay mutable

// Global variables for options
char *FileName;
char message[100];
int verbose = 0; // Verbose flag
int pivotingRule = 0; // 0 for first-improvement, 1 for best-improvement
int neighborhoodStrategy = 0; // 0 for transpose, 1 for exchange, 2 for insert
int initialSolutionMethod = 0; // 0 for random permutation, 1 for CW heuristic

void readOpts(int argc, char **argv) {
    char opt;
    FileName = NULL;
    char *pivotingRuleStr, *neighborhoodStrategyStr, *initialSolutionMethodStr;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "i:p:n:s:v")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 'i': // Instance file
                FileName = strdup(optarg);
                break;
            case 'p': // Pivoting rule
                pivotingRule = atoi(optarg);
                pivotingRuleStr = (pivotingRule == 0) ? "first-improvement" : "best-improvement";
                break;
            case 'n': // Neighborhood strategy
                neighborhoodStrategy = atoi(optarg);
                switch(neighborhoodStrategy) {
                    case 0: neighborhoodStrategyStr = "transpose"; break;
                    case 1: neighborhoodStrategyStr = "exchange"; break;
                    case 2: neighborhoodStrategyStr = "insert"; break;
                    default: neighborhoodStrategyStr = "unknown"; break;
                }
                break;
            case 's': // Initial solution method
                initialSolutionMethod = atoi(optarg);
                initialSolutionMethodStr = (initialSolutionMethod == 0) ? "random permutation" : "CW heuristic";
                break;
            case 'v': // Verbose mode
                verbose = 1;
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Option -%c not recognized.\n", opt);
        }
    }

    if (verbose) {
        if (FileName != NULL) {
            verbose_message("Input file selected");
        }
        sprintf(message, "Pivoting rule selected is %s", pivotingRuleStr);
        verbose_message(message);
        sprintf(message, "Neighborhood strategy selected is %s", neighborhoodStrategyStr);
        verbose_message(message);
        sprintf(message, "Initial solution method selected is %s", initialSolutionMethodStr);
        verbose_message(message);
    }

    if (!FileName) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No instance file provided (use -i <instance_name>). Exiting.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}


int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    long int i,j, k, l, step;
    long int *currentSolution;
    int cost, newCost, best_k, best_l, bestCost, oldCost;
    int breakOuterLoop = 0; // Flag to signal breaking out of the outer loop

    /* Do not buffer output */
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    setbuf(stderr,NULL);

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("No instance file provided (use -i <instance_name>). Exiting.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Read parameters */
    readOpts(argc, argv);

    /* Read instance file */
    CostMat = readInstance(FileName);
    printf("Data have been read from instance file. Size of instance = %ld.\n\n", PSize);

    /* initialize random number generator, deterministically based on instance.
     * To do this we simply set the seed to the sum of elements in the matrix, so it is constant per-instance,
     but (most likely) varies between instances */
    Seed = (long int) 0;
    for (i=0; i < PSize; ++i)
        for (j=0; j < PSize; ++j)
            Seed += (long int) CostMat[i][j];
    printf("Seed used to initialize RNG: %ld.\n\n", Seed);

    /* starts time measurement */
    start_timers();

    /* A solution is just a vector of int with the same size as the instance */
    currentSolution = (long int *)malloc(PSize * sizeof(long int));

    if (initialSolutionMethod == 0) {
        verbose_message("    Creating random solution...");
        createRandomSolution(currentSolution);
        verbose_message("    Done.");
    } else if (initialSolutionMethod == 1) {
        verbose_message("    Creating CW heuristic based solution...");
        /* Initialize the attractiveness array and a flag array to keep track of inserted elements */
        long int *attractiveness = (long int *)malloc(PSize * sizeof(long int));
        int *inserted = (int *)calloc(PSize, sizeof(int));  // calloc initializes to 0

        for (i = 0; i < PSize; i++) {
            attractiveness[i] = 0;
            for (k=0; k < PSize; k++) {
                for (j = k; j < PSize; j++) {
                    attractiveness[i] += CostMat[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        for (int step = 0; step < PSize; step++) {
            // Find the most attractive element that hasn't been inserted yet
            long int maxAttr = -1;
            int maxIdx = -1;
            for (i = 0; i < PSize; i++) {
                if (!inserted[i] && (maxAttr < attractiveness[i])) {
                    maxAttr = attractiveness[i];
                    maxIdx = i;
                }
            }
            inserted[maxIdx] = 1; // inserted
            currentSolution[step] = maxIdx;
            /* No need to update attractiveness since it's only used to determine the initial insertion order */
        }

        free(attractiveness);
        free(inserted);

        verbose_message("    CW heuristic based solution created.");

        // Compute and print the cost of the CW heuristic based initial solution
        newCost = computeCost(currentSolution);
        sprintf(message, "Cost of the CW heuristic based initial solution = %d\n", newCost);
        verbose_message(message);

    } else {
        printf("Unknown method for initial solution (should be 0 or 1, got %i).", initialSolutionMethod);
    }


    /* Print solution */
    printf("Initial solution:\n");
    for (j=0; j < PSize; j++)
        printf(" %ld", currentSolution[j]);
    printf("\n");

    /* Compute cost of solution and print it */
    cost = computeCost(currentSolution);
    bestCost = cost;
    sprintf(message, "Cost of the initial solution = %d\n", cost);
    verbose_message(message);

    swapAdjacentElements(currentSolution, 56);
    bestCost = cost + computeSwapCostDifference(currentSolution, 56, 57);

    verbose_message("    Starting main loop...");
    oldCost = cost;
    i = 0;
    if (neighborhoodStrategy == 0) {  // transpose
        if (pivotingRule) { // transpose best improvement
            while (i < EARLY_STOPPING) {
                sprintf(message, "Starting iteration n°%li...", i);
                verbose_message(message);
                i++;
                best_k = -1; // -1 means no k improves the model
                long long int costDifference;
                for (k = 0; k < PSize - 1; k++) { // Note the change here to ensure we don't go out of bounds
                    // Predict the new cost without actually swapping first
                    costDifference = computeSwapCostDifference(currentSolution, k, k + 1);
                    printf("%i\n", costDifference);

                    if (costDifference > 0) {
                        sprintf(message, "Found a neighbor augmenting the cost by %lli, new cost is %lli",
                                costDifference, bestCost + costDifference);
                        verbose_message(message);
                        bestCost = oldCost + costDifference; // Update the best known cost
                        best_k = k; // Remember the position that leads to the improvement
                    }
                    // No need to swap back since we didn't actually swap; we calculated the cost difference directly
                }
                if (best_k >= 0) {
                    // Now perform the actual swap for the best improvement found
                    swapAdjacentElements(currentSolution, best_k);
                    sprintf(message, "Performing swap at position %d for improvement.", best_k);
                    verbose_message(message);
                } else {
                    verbose_message("Found a local optimum!");
                    break; // Local optimum reached
                }

                if (i >= EARLY_STOPPING) {
                    sprintf(message, "EARLY STOPPING (reached %li iterations).", i);
                    verbose_message(message);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else { // transpose first improvement
            while (i < EARLY_STOPPING) {
                sprintf(message, "Starting iteration n°%li...", i);
                verbose_message(message);
                i++;
                best_k = -1;
                for (k = 0; k <= PSize - 1; k++) {
                    swapAdjacentElements(currentSolution, k);
                    newCost = computeCost(currentSolution);
                    if (newCost > bestCost + FIRST_THRESHOLD) {
                        sprintf(message, "Found a neighbor augmenting the cost by %d, new cost is %d",
                                newCost - bestCost, newCost);
                        verbose_message(message);
                        bestCost = newCost;
                        best_k = k;
                        break; // Don't put back in place and leave the k-loop
                    } else {
                        swapAdjacentElements(currentSolution, k); // Put it back in place if no improvement
                    }
                }
                // If best k found, don't do anything as we didn't revert the change earlier
                if (best_k < 0) {
                    if (IS_FIRST_THRESHOLD_MUTABLE && FIRST_THRESHOLD >= MIN_FIRST_THRESHOLD) {
                        FIRST_THRESHOLD /= FIRST_THRESHOLD_FACTOR_REDUCTION;
                        sprintf(message, "FIRST_THRESHOLD reduced to %li.", FIRST_THRESHOLD); verbose_message(message);
                    }
                    else {
                        verbose_message("Found a local optimum!");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (i >= EARLY_STOPPING) {
                    sprintf(message, "EARLY STOPPING (reached %li iterations).", i);
                    verbose_message(message);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (neighborhoodStrategy == 1) { // exchange
        if (pivotingRule) { // exchange best improvement
            while (i < EARLY_STOPPING) {
                sprintf(message, "Starting iteration n°%li...", i);
                verbose_message(message);
                i++;
                best_k = -1; best_l = -1; breakOuterLoop = 0;
                for (k = 0; k <= PSize - 1; k++) {
                    for (l = 0; l <= PSize - 1; l++) {
                        if (l == k) continue;
                        swapElements(currentSolution, k, l);
                        newCost = computeCost(currentSolution);
                        if (newCost > bestCost) {
                            sprintf(message, "Found a neighbor augmenting the cost by %d, new cost is %d",
                                    newCost - bestCost, newCost);
                            verbose_message(message);
                            bestCost = newCost; best_k = k; best_l = l;
                        }
                        swapElements(currentSolution, k, l); // Put it back in place anyway
                    }
                    if (breakOuterLoop) break;
                }
                if (best_k >= 0) swapElements(currentSolution, best_k, best_l); // found a better k, l
                else {
                    verbose_message("Found a local optimum!");
                    break;
                } // local optimum

                if (i >= EARLY_STOPPING) {
                    sprintf(message, "EARLY STOPPING (reached %li iterations).", i);
                    verbose_message(message);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else { // exchange first improvement
            while (i < EARLY_STOPPING) {
                sprintf(message, "Starting iteration n°%li...", i);
                verbose_message(message);
                i++;
                best_k = -1; best_l = -1;
                breakOuterLoop = 0;
                for (k = 0; k <= PSize - 1; k++) {
                    best_l = -1;
                    for (l = 0; l <= PSize - 1; l++) {
                        if (l == k) continue; // Skip comparing an element with itself
                        swapElements(currentSolution, k, l);
                        newCost = computeCost(currentSolution);
                        if (newCost > bestCost + FIRST_THRESHOLD) {
                            sprintf(message, "Found a neighbor augmenting the cost by %d, new cost is %d",
                                    newCost - bestCost, newCost);
                            verbose_message(message);
                            bestCost = newCost; best_k = k; best_l = l;
                            breakOuterLoop = 1; // Signal to break out of the outer loop
                            break; // Exit the inner l-loop
                        } else {
                            swapElements(currentSolution, k, l); // Put it back in place if no improvement
                        }
                    }
                    if (breakOuterLoop) break; // Check the flag and exit the outer k-loop if signaled
                }
                // If best k found, don't do anything as we didn't revert the change earlier
                if (best_k < 0) {
                    if (IS_FIRST_THRESHOLD_MUTABLE && FIRST_THRESHOLD >= MIN_FIRST_THRESHOLD) {
                        FIRST_THRESHOLD /= FIRST_THRESHOLD_FACTOR_REDUCTION;
                        sprintf(message, "FIRST_THRESHOLD reduced to %li.", FIRST_THRESHOLD); verbose_message(message);
                    }
                    else {
                        verbose_message("Found a local optimum!");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (i >= EARLY_STOPPING) {
                    sprintf(message, "EARLY STOPPING (reached %li iterations).", i);
                    verbose_message(message);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (neighborhoodStrategy == 2) { // insert
        if (pivotingRule) { // insert best improvement
            while (i < EARLY_STOPPING) {
                sprintf(message, "Starting iteration n°%li...", i);
                verbose_message(message);
                i++;
                best_k = -1; best_l = -1; breakOuterLoop = 0;
                for (k = 0; k <= PSize - 1; k++) {
                    for (l = 0; l <= PSize - 1; l++) {
                        if (l == k) continue;
                        insertElement(currentSolution, k, l);
                        newCost = computeCost(currentSolution);
                        if (newCost > bestCost) {
                            sprintf(message, "Found a neighbor augmenting the cost by %d, new cost is %d",
                                    newCost - bestCost, newCost);
                            verbose_message(message);
                            bestCost = newCost; best_k = k; best_l = l;
                        }
                        undoInsertion(currentSolution, k, l); // Put it back in place anyway
                    }
                    if (breakOuterLoop) break;
                }
                if (best_k >= 0) insertElement(currentSolution, best_k, best_l); // found a better k, l
                else {
                    verbose_message("Found a local optimum!");
                    break;
                } // local optimum

                if (i >= EARLY_STOPPING) {
                    sprintf(message, "EARLY STOPPING (reached %li iterations).", i);
                    verbose_message(message);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {  // insert first improvement
            while (i < EARLY_STOPPING) {
                sprintf(message, "Starting iteration n°%li...", i);
                verbose_message(message);
                i++;
                best_k = -1;
                breakOuterLoop = 0;
                for (k = 0; k <= PSize - 1; k++) {
                    best_l = -1;
                    for (l = 0; l <= PSize - 1; l++) {
                        if (l == k) continue; // Skip comparing an element with itself
                        insertElement(currentSolution, k, l);
                        newCost = computeCost(currentSolution);
                        if (newCost > bestCost + FIRST_THRESHOLD) {
                            sprintf(message, "Found a neighbor augmenting the cost by %d, new cost is %d",
                                    newCost - bestCost, newCost);
                            verbose_message(message);
                            bestCost = newCost; best_k = k; best_l = l;
                            breakOuterLoop = 1; // Signal to break out of the outer loop
                            break; // Exit the inner l-loop
                        } else {
                            undoInsertion(currentSolution, k, l); // Put it back in place if no improvement
                        }
                    }
                    if (breakOuterLoop) break; // Check the flag and exit the outer k-loop if signaled
                }
                // If best k found, don't do anything as we didn't revert the change earlier
                if (best_k < 0) {
                    if (IS_FIRST_THRESHOLD_MUTABLE && FIRST_THRESHOLD >= MIN_FIRST_THRESHOLD) {
                        FIRST_THRESHOLD /= FIRST_THRESHOLD_FACTOR_REDUCTION;
                        sprintf(message, "FIRST_THRESHOLD reduced to %li.", FIRST_THRESHOLD); verbose_message(message);
                    }
                    else {
                        verbose_message("Found a local optimum!");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (i >= EARLY_STOPPING) {
                    sprintf(message, "EARLY STOPPING (reached %li iterations).", i);
                    verbose_message(message);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    verbose_message("    Done.");

    printf("Solution after optimization:\n");
    for (j=0; j < PSize; j++)
        printf(" %ld", currentSolution[j]);
    printf("\n");

    /* Recompute cost of solution after the exchange move */
    /* There are some more efficient way to do this, instead of recomputing everything... */
    newCost = computeCost(currentSolution);
    sprintf(message, "Cost of the new solution = %i\n", newCost);
    verbose_message(message);

    cost = oldCost;

    if (newCost == cost) {
        verbose_message("Second solution is as good as first one");
    }
    else if (newCost > cost) {
        sprintf(message, "Second solution is better than first one by %.2f%%.", ((float)(newCost - cost) / cost) * 100.0);
        verbose_message(message); }
    else {
        verbose_message("Second solution is worse than first one");
    }

    printf("Time elapsed since we started the timer: %g\n\n", elapsed_time(VIRTUAL));

    verbose_message("'main' completed successfully.");
    printf("%s, %f, %d, %d, %.4f\n", FileName, elapsed_time(VIRTUAL), cost, newCost, ((float)(newCost - cost) / cost));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This might be better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com, just as a suggestion. Here and there, it would help getting a [mcve] plus according numbers concerning the performance. Also, how do you compile (hint: optimization)?

Comment: First of all, how do you measure? Have you build with optimizations enabled?

Comment: You should use `memmove` instead of a loop (though a clever compiler may replace the loop). In fact, the container might not be suited for the operation but we can't tell without the code of `computeCost`. Doing a copy might be faster than undoing things and it might help you to use multiple thread (also dependent of `computeCost`).

Comment: You might want to create a second working structure that is in essence the (possibly signed) magnitude and position of each component in the array and then sort it by value. Then you can use a greedy algorithm to get something like an optimum answer by shuffling around the biggest array components that will make most difference. 250x250 is just big enough that your algorithm may need to be cache aware. Try with smaller sizes /2, /5, /10 to see where the performance breakpoints are.

Comment: Assuming `computeCost` just compute *"sum of the elements in the superior triangle"*, then I do not think you should recompute the whole matrix but only the line *incrementally*. This requires to compute *partial sums* (for each row and for each columns).

Comment: For the compiler, I use gcc: "gcc -O3 -Wall "

Comment: What do you mean "with optimization enabled" ? I will add the Makefile instructions to the post

Comment: I added computeCost function to the post

Comment: How to use memmove ? I don't know what it is. Do you have a link I can look at to get informed ?

Comment: There is insufficient information in this question to answer. An arbitrary cost function could have its optimum anywhere, with no clue about where that is from trial alterations in the inputs. If no properties of the cost function that would aid the search are known, such as any sort of transitivity, monotonicity, or limits on how much it can change for certain amounts of input change, there is no basis for conducting anything other than an exhaustive search.

Comment: Additionally, the descriptions in the question are inadequate. “Exchange 2 elements of the permutation vector” is reasonably clear; a permutation vector on *n* elements is likely a sequence of the integers in [0, *n*) in some order, and an exchange of 2 elements is likely a swap of any two elements in that sequence. But “make an insertion of an element of the permutation vector elsewhere” is incomprehensible, as there is no context for “elsewhere.” Is putting a 3 in France an insertion of an element elsewhere?…

Comment: … Similarly, the “pivotation” rules “first improvement” and “best improvement” lack all context and are not rules.

Comment: `memmove` is a standard C library function. “I should have a 20x slower code for this exercise” is easily accomplished; simply run the program twenty times and use only the last result.

Comment: It would really help if you could publish your entire program here. What is the value of `PSize`, `EARLY_STOPPING`? What are the dimensions of `costMat`? `breakOuterLoop` is never changed. These things matter to choose speedups. We would really like an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For C, we would like a _single_ `.c` file [_with_ (e.g.) `#include <stdio.h>`]. But, _no_ (e.g.) `#include "myprogram.h"`. For runtime errors, it should compile cleanly. We should be able to download, build, and run it on our local systems [if we so choose].

Comment: `insertElement` and `undoInsertion` are O(n) operations (to just swap `k` and `l`). If you make `currentSolution` a [doubly] linked list instead of a vector, these operations become O(1). From call-to-call of `computeCost` it seems like there are parts that are invariant from the previous call, so don't iterate over the entire amount each time. You _may_ get better cache performance if you pre-sort `currentSolution`